# Is it good or bad to create a thread in function object constructor by passing the dereferenced `this` pointer by reference to the thread object?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

Is it good or bad to create a thread in function object constructor by passing the dereferenced `this` pointer by reference to the thread object?

1. Is there any problem in below code?
2. Any improvement can be made on it to reach below objective?

The objective is to gracefully end the thread when the class object is out of scope.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

class MyThread {
private:
    std::atomic<bool> exit;
    std::thread t;
public:
    MyThread() : exit(false) {
        t = std::thread(std::ref(*this));
    }
    ~MyThread() {
        exit.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        if (t.joinable()) {
            t.join();
        }
    }
    void operator()() {
        while (!exit.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
            std::cout << "."; // some more meaningful work here
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    MyThread t;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It might work occasionally, but it's unsafe. It potentially generates a race condition, because you start the thread on an object that hasn't finished its construction yet, resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: Specifically, this is very dangerous if an exception is thrown in the constructor.

Comment: @Frank this is an important case indeed, but I think there are other situations as well, enough to classify the pattern as unsafe in general.

Comment: @A.S.H May you explain why starting a thread on an object in construction results in undefined behavior? And where is the race condition?

Comment: @etoricky Think about what happens when you try to do the meaningful work in `operator()()` and the object isn't fully constructed yet. Think about trying to derive from this class when `operator()()` calls a `virtual` function. It's just asking for trouble.

Comment: @David Schwartz Yes I agree with you. So now I think leaving the constructor empty and move the constructor body to another function `void Start() {t = std::thread(std::ref(*this));}` and `MyThread m; m.Start();`. Is it a lot better?

Comment: @etoricky IMO, yes, it's much better.

Comment: Thanks @DavidSchwartz for the additional feedback. Please feel free to edit and add your valuable thoughts I'd be grateful. Etoricky I believe that an explicit `start` function is the way to go, and can be made in a bullet-proof way, with an object that is fully constructed and in *consistent* state. Calling from the constructor is simply unsafe in the *general case* and at most we may say that it may be made to work *"for most implementations", but not by the language's semantics, IMHO.